# Python Lambda usage

Tags: python, lambda

Im trying to learn how to utilize the lambda function and i am having some difficulties.

example from HomeWork.

i have the following functions

```
def square(x):
    return x**2

def incr(x):
    return x+1
```

i need to create a function called 'repeated' that will take one of the above functions + an integer and will return some value that depends on the times the functions have been called IE:

```
repeated (incr,4)(2)
6

repeated (square,2)(5)
625
```

using a 'compose' function.

```
def compose(f,g):
    return lambda x:f(g(x))
```

thank in advance for an explanation.

Comment: Have you tried recursing?

Comment: Have you been introduced to `reduce()` yet?

Comment: No i havent tryed recursing, and no im not fully familier to the reduce() function we should learn about it in the next few leasons i belive.

Comment: I think the teacher wants us to provide an answer with a lambda function that will take a function as an argument with an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`repeated` needs to return a callable too; `compose()` can produce that callable for you, but you need to apply it multiple times:

```
def repeated(f, count):
    callable = f
    for _ in range(count - 1):
        callable = compose(f, callable)
    return callable
```

So if `count` is `1`, the original `f()` is returned. For `count = 2`, `f(f())` is returned, etc.

Comment: just one thing , why do i need to save f in a diffrent var?

Comment: Because you need access to the unaltered function each iteration. You don't want to wrap the stacked callable in itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you should use a `lambda`, you can use recursion like this:

```
def repeated(func, times):
    return lambda x: repeated(func, times - 1)(func(x)) if times > 0 else x
```

what `repeated` return is a function waiting for an argument, `x`,and then it activates itself `times` times (descriptive...) on `x`

When it should no longer activate itself (in other words, times <= 0, it stops and returns the x the **last call** received.

You can use `compose` in the same manner as follows:

If you want to use `compose` you can do this:

```
def repeated(func, times):
    return compose(func, repeated(func, times-1)) if times > 0 else lambda x
```

What this does is just call `compose` recursively `times - 1` more times, using `repeated`, until no more composing is needed.

### Edit:

Python's standard implementation and recursion don't get along too well, both of these solution are correct, but using a loop is more pythonic. Another answer is available that does just that.